# How to test memory usage for different parts of the project in Python?

Tags: python, memory

I try to compare different algorithms' performance in one script. Without using profiler, are there any methods we could use to estimate the memory usage at the end of each algorithm implementation?

```
def main():
    test_case = open('text.txt', 'r')
    for line in test_case.readlines(): #input different datasets
       #do something in Alg1
       #evaluate memory usage in Alg1
       #do something in Alg2
       #evaluate memory usage in Alg2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Linux or Mac OS X;

You can use the standard library module [`resource`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html#resource.getrusage) to get the total memory consumption as `bytes` for the calling process:

```
>>> import resource
>>> resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
19968000
```

Comment: Do you mean I put your second line at #evaluate memory usage in Alg each time?